# What do I put in “contentURL” for a video? The original url the video came from?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

This is the prompt I’m getting from Google Search Console: Either "contentUrl" or "embedUrl" should be specified

What do I put in “contentURL” for a video? The original url the video came from?

Comment: What is the context here?  Are you implementing structured data?  If so which one?